# How does LaTeX compute the bounding box of a character?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontsize, font-encodings

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\def\text{0}
\newlength\len

\settowidth \len\text
width:  \the\len % width: 5.47499pt

\settoheight\len\text
height: \the\len % height: 7.17827pt

\end{document}
```

I want to understand exactly how LaTeX comes up with those two numbers. I think I have come close to the answer, but I'm not there yet.

First, when we advise the article class to select a font size of 11pt, it actually decides to select a font size of 10.95pt. Fair enough. [latex/base/classes.dtx](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/base/classes.dtx):

```
%<*11pt>
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%  %% \@xipt equals 10.95
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
%</11pt>
```

Now, Latin Modern does not come with 10.95pt characters, so we need to take a character of a different size and scale it. The Latin Modern configuration files tell us that for 10.95pt we should take the 10pt character and scale it up. [latex/lm/t1lmss.fd](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd):

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmss}{m}{n}
     {<-8.5> ec-lmss8
      <8.5-9.5> ec-lmss9      <9.5-11>  ec-lmss10
      <11-15.5> ec-lmss12     <15.5-> ec-lmss17
      }{}
```

Next, we need to inspect the font file with a font editor. When I open [Latin Modern](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss10.pfb) with FontForge, it tells me that `0` has a width of 500 UPM (units per Em), (probably?) a height of 656 UPM and that one Em consists of 1000 UPM in each direction. In order to turn those values into `pt`, the Em is scaled to the requested point size (10.95 in our case). Okay, let's do the math:

Width: 500 * 0.001 * 10.95 = 5.475pt (I guess that is close enough to 5.47499pt)

Height: 656 * 0.001 * 10.95 = 7.1832pt (This is not so close to 7.17827pt...)

Questions:

1. Why does my computed value does not match the one LaTeX outputs? Floating-point calculations are not exact and I don't know how LaTeX performs those calculations, but I have the feeling that an error of ~0.005 after just two multiplications with relatively nice numbers is too large. And the error in the first case is much smaller, too. So something seems to be off.
2. I wrote before the height is *probably* 656 UPM. Actually, Font Forge nicely displays the width of a glyph and its left and right bearing, but (for me surprisingly) not the height. As far as I understand it, a font designer defines for each glyph a custom width and height (correct?), so I would expect a font editor to show this width and height equally, which does not seem to be the case. There is a line at 656 UPM that *could be* the height, but I am not entirely sure. How do I retrieve the height of a glyph?
3. Latin Modern comes in different formats, such as [lm/fonts/afm/public/lm/lmss10.afm](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/fonts/afm/public/lm/lmss10.afm), [lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf) or [lm/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss10.pfb](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss10.pfb). I inspected the `lmss10.pfb`. What decides which one is actually used?

Comment: tex doesn't read the pfb. It uses the values in the tfm-file. You can convert such a tfm to something readable with tftopl.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That was a very helpful hint, thanks! The tfm-file (which stores the height of each glyph) is a TeX-specific thing. And as mentioned before, my font editor just shows width and bearing for each glyph. Does that mean designer-specified custom heights per glyph are TeX-specific and not part of a font in general? Maybe FontForge is just strange, but I think there must be a reason not to show height alongside the width which would be the obvious way.

Comment: classically tex would be using metafont font when the tfm (with the metrics) and pk (glyph bitmaps would be generated from the same source. with non-metafont fonts the tfm is usually mechanically constructed from the afm or similar information. for your question 3, the `.afm` is adobe font metrics, tex doesn't use them at all but they are usually used to generate the tfm for type 1 fonts. pdftex doesn't read the .otf  font (xelatex and luatex do)  the pfb is a type1 version of a subset of the opentype font that is used by pdftex.

Comment: also note that fontforge is displaying lengths in postscript points (1in/72)  but tex is displaying them in tex points (1in/72.27)